How to increase the arrows' lengths in a plantUML activity diagram?
I created the following activity diagram using plantUML:
@startuml


title Usecase <<Place Order>> Success Scenario 

skinparam ActivityBackgroundColor Business
skinparam ActivityBorderColor Crimson
skinparam ActivityBorderThickness 2
skinparam ActivityFontSize 14
skinparam ActivityFontStyle normal
skinparam ArrowColor Crimson
skinparam ParticipantPadding 200

|Supplier|
start
:Visit Offer Details page;
|System|
:Display offer details;
|Supplier|
:Click "Placer Order" button;
|System|
:Show order form;
|Supplier|
:Specify desired quantity;
:Confirm order details;
|System|
:Save order;
end;


@enduml

Which compiles to:

The problem is that the generated arrows are too short which, IMO, makes the diagram ugly.
I consulted the answers to the question How to make PlantUML left/right/up/down arrow longer? but they seem to use a syntax that is incompatible with the way activity diagrams are currently edited in plantUML.
I also went through the All Skin Parameters page in the plantUML docs, but failed to find any option that allows changing the default minimum arrow length so I was wondering if there are other means that could be employed in order to achieve the same result.

The referenced link is invalid. Howwever, the arrows are (almost)  as defined by UML.There they use plain triangles with no curve on top.

@qwerty_so I fixed the link. The issue is not with the shape of the arrows but with their lengths, which is very small. I don't think the arrows' length is defined by UML.

I just compared to the UML spec (around pp. 410) of UML 2.5.1. Actually the difference is that they use open arrows a bit longer. The filling  with the half circle is wrong. But AFAIK you can't change it in plantuml. It's not the only place where they differ from the standard :-(
